# When i config cloud configuration in GitLab authentication error comes

Tags: git, gitlab, cloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXln4.png)

## This my application.yml

server:
port: 9196

spring:
application:
name: CONFIG-SERVER
cloud:
config:
server:
git:
uri: https://git.misynergy.com/imal/cloud-application-config

eureka:
client:
register-with-eureka: true
fetch-registry: true
service-url:
defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
instance:
hostname: localhost

```
# This is my app start point

package com.microservice.cloudconfig;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableConfigServer
public class CloudConfigApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudConfigApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```